# Sum a column based on matching a cell reference in another?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The yellow cells both have the formula `=A2`. I want a formula I can put into the red cells, which sums the blue cells if the cell reference in the yellow cells matches that of the row's green cell.

[image: EXAMPLE]

Since column A is non-unique, I need it to operate based on cell references, instead of string matching.

For example, `C2` has the value `3` because `A2` is referenced twice in the yellow cells, and the corresponding blue cells sum of up to `3` (= `F2+F3`=`2+1`). And `C4` has the value `0` because `A4` isn't referenced once inside the yellow cells, despite having the same string match.

Answer (score 0):

You can try array formula:

```
=SUM($F$2:$F$10*IFERROR(ADDRESS(ROW(A2),1,4)=SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT($E$2:$E$10),"=",""),0))
```

[image]